# Keeping drop down option selected after submitting data into db issue

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make a selected drop down option stay selected once the value has been inserted into the db after pressing submit. My code is working but it isn't. I currently have two options which are American and Fried Chicken, these are food cuisines. When i click on American, American is submitted into the DB, however the Fried Chicken option stays selected on the page and visa versa.

The information in my drop down menu is generated dynamically from the my DB. Where have i gone wrong.

```
   $get_cats = "SELECT * FROM Rest_Category";
                    $run_cats = mysqli_query($dbc, $get_cats);
                    while ($row_cats = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)) {

                        $CategoryID = $row_cats['CategoryID'];
                        $Cuisine_category = $row_cats['Cuisine_category'];
                        $selected = $Cuisine_category ? 'selected' : '';

                        echo"<option ".$selected." value=' $CategoryID'>$Cuisine_category </option>";

                    }
```

**Table structure**

*Rest_Category*

```
     +-----------+------------+-----------+--------+
    | CategoryID | Cuisine_category | Category_img |         
    +-----------+------------+-----------+---------+
    |         1 | American          | img          | 
    |         2 | Fried Chicken     | img          | 
    +-----------+-------------------+--------------+
```

*Rest details*

```
     +-----------+------------+-----------+--------+
    | Restaurant_ID | Restaurant_name | Cat_ID     |         
    +-----------+------------+-----------+---------+
    |         1     | McDonalds       | 1          | 
    |         2     | KFC             | 1          |
    +-----------+-------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Is the selected value stored in the `Rest_Category` table? This line `$selected = $Cuisine_category ? 'selected' : '';` doesn't make sense, as you are just checking if `$Cuisine_category` exists, which it does as you defined it above. Instead it should be something like `$selected = ($StoredValueinDB == $Cuisine_category) ? 'selected' : '';`

Comment: @Sean Hi, yes the values are stored in rest_category. That line you suggested does not work, but the previously line slightly does as it selects the option just the wrong one

Comment: How do you store the selected value? Do you have a column for the selected? Do all rows get updated with the selected value? Could you share a sample of your table structure, showing the rows and the selected value?

Comment: The values id number for each row is inserted into the table. Then i have a different table which defines each id and name, each row in the table can have a different category. Okay give me 5 minutes to update my question

Comment: @Sean table structure added